# Why PDcurses shows strings differently from source file and stream?

Tags: c, stream, ncurses, widechar, pdcurses

Here is my C code:

```
int main(){
  _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
  FILE* myFile = fopen("text.txt", "r");
  wchar_t line[100];
  fgetws(line,100,myFile);
  clear();
  initscr();
  addwstr(L"♠♣♥♦\n");
  addwstr(line);
  refresh();
  getchar();
  endwin();
  return 0;
}
```

the text.txt file is just:

```
♠♣♥♦
```

The first one shows ok, but the second is just a serie of weird characters. Anybody knows why?

Comment: did you try setting the locale?

Comment: the platform might be relevant

Comment: hmm probably C compiler doesn't do UTF-8 here in the literal

Comment: thanks for the comments! I'm using MinGW from Windows 10 and editing the c file in Atom.

Answer (score 0):

gcc will represent the argument in the second case as an array of `wchar_t` (using the **`L"`** prefix), while `fgetws` returns an array of `wchar_t` (either UCS-2 or UCS-4, depending on the platform: usually the former if you're using Windows).

However, the data read from the file could be *different* because:

- the byte-order differs which would be because
- the `fgetws` function expects (or does not expect) a byte-order mark
- and the actual data did not match its expectations.

You could see this difference by a dump (hexdump or od) of the data file and printing the actual data read/used in the test-program as an array of numbers.  Since these wide-characters use *multibyte* encoding for their external representation, if there's a mismatch on byte-ordering you'll see garbage.

The external file, for instance, might be encoded as UTF-8 while (this sounds like MinGW), the `fgetws` would expect only UTF-16 (or the reverse).  But starting by seeing exactly what the **numbers** look like will show you the problem.